# Install Adaptec RAID 6405 on Ubuntu 12.04 (3.13.0-37-generic)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, raid

I'm trying to install an Adaptec RAID controller on Ubuntu 12.04. So far, I've downloaded different versions of the driver, but executing the specified commands yields some errors.

```
sudo dpkg -i aacraid-1.2.1-29900-Ubuntu11.04+11.10+12.04-all.deb
```

gives

```
(Reading database ... 220186 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking aacraid (from aacraid-1.2.1-29900-Ubuntu11.04+11.10+12.04-all.deb) ...
aacraid version 1.2.1-29900 installation started ...
****** PROBLEM *******
No prebuilt aacraid module for 3.13.0-37-generic
driver in OS may be more advanced than package
**********************
dpkg: error processing aacraid-1.2.1-29900-Ubuntu11.04+11.10+12.04-all.deb (--install):
    subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
    aacraid-1.2.1-29900-Ubuntu11.04+11.10+12.04-all.deb
```

and what seems to be a newer version of the driver also gives a (less informative) error.

```
sudo dpkg -i aacraid-1.2.1-40300-Ubuntu11.10+12.04+12.04.1+12.04.2-all.deb
```

outputs:

```
(Reading database ... 220186 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking aacraid (from aacraid-1.2.1-40300-Ubuntu11.10+12.04+12.04.1+12.04.2-all.deb) ...
aacraid version 1.2.1-40300 installation started ...
No driver archive found.
dpkg: error processing aacraid-1.2.1-40300-Ubuntu11.10+12.04+12.04.1+12.04.2-all.deb (--install):
    subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Erros were encountered while processing:
    aacraid-1.2.1-40300-Ubuntu11.10+12.04+12.04.1+12.04.2-all.deb
```

With the intention of building the driver myself, I downloaded the "Dynamic Kernel Module Source and Drivers" from adaptec.com, but this only contains an .rpm package and a readme that doesn't tell me how to build from source.

By now, I'm in a state where lsmod shows aacraid, but I'm not sure how it got there and what I should be doing/trying next.

Note that there in both 29900 and 40300 there are archives containing aacraid.ko, but the versions I think I should be supplying to insmod gives an "Invalid module format" error.

Is there someone out there who can help me make sense of this? I'm not sure what my options are now..

Notes:

- Ubuntu 12.04 is already up and running on a harddisk that is not part of the RAID controller.
- The controller has four disks, all are visible, two of them are mounted via fstab.
- The other two also seem mounted, not sure how or where. I want to use these other two disks in RAID-1 configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did (I asked adaptec at http://ask.adaptec.com/app/account/questions/detail/i_id/117462)

Go to http://ask.adaptec.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17202 and download the *minimally tested* driver

Essentially follow the instructions in 
Ubuntu Server/Ubuntu 12.04 LTS/Ubuntu 12.04.2 thru 12.04.5 LTS/Installing Ubuntu 12.04.2 thru 12.04.X LTS on Adaptec RAID Controllers.txt

1. `apt-get install build-essential dkms`
2. Unpack the archive.
3. Install the deb file:
   Ubuntu Server/Ubuntu 12.04 LTS/Ubuntu 12.04.2 thru 12.04.5 LTS/aacraid_1.2.1.40700-1_all.deb
4. `dkms add -m aacraid -v 1.2.1.40700`
5. `dkms build -m aacraid -v 1.2.1.40700`
6. `dkms install -m aacraid -v 1.2.1.40700`
7. reboot

And after the reboot the host should come up with the new driver.  If something fails you can go back to the old initrd copy it makes (/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic.old-dkms in my case)

You can verify it via

```
/usr/StorMan/arcconf getconfig 1
```

if you have that installed.

Comment: Hi Brian and muru, thank your kindly for your responses. I have not tried this yet, will report back after I have.

Comment: I've accepted your answer! :) Note that I had to install libstdc++5 as well to be able to execute arcconf.

Comment: So how does one `Install the deb file`? Is it `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/file.deb` and then `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: @Jongosi yes although you shouldn't need the `sudo apt-get install -f` part.