# VMWare passthrough of Adaptec RAID 6405 on client Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, vmware, raid

A while back, I asked this question on how to install Adaptec RAID 6405 on Ubuntu 12.04 and got a helpful answer :) [Install Adaptec RAID 6405 on Ubuntu 12.04 (3.13.0-37-generic)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534782/install-adaptec-raid-6405-on-ubuntu-12-04-3-13-0-37-generic)

Now, we are running a server with VMWare ESXI 6. We're trying to achieve the same thing again, i.e. getting Adaptec RAID to work, this time on an Ubuntu 14.04 guest (virtual machine). We have installed the Adaptec RAID 6405 drivers on the VMWare host and have detected the PCI device and set it as passthrough for the guest.

Now, in the Ubuntu 14.04 guest, we can see the PCI device when running `lspci`, it shows as an Adaptec RAID Series 6. However, `sudo lshw -C disk` does not yield any of the disks.

We've tried both the latest driver as well as the minimal driver (see previous question) but no luck.

What can I do to get the RAID controller to work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, we found it: The Adaptec RAID BIOS was outdated, which resulted in Ubuntu 14.04 not recognizing it. We updated it and now the controller and its harddisks are recognized on installation of Ubuntu already :)